# Overriding a virtual method based on template type sign

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to override a virtual method based on the members signedness, but somehow I don't get it right.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 which doesn't support full C++11 but also in gcc it doesn't compile.

```
#ifndef SIGNED_TEMPLATE_H_
#define SIGNED_TEMPLATE_H_

#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base(void) {}
    virtual ~Base(void) {}

    virtual bool toValue(int *p) = 0;

    void Signed(bool bSigned) { mSigned = bSigned; }
    bool Signed(void) const { return mSigned; }

private:
    bool mSigned;
};

template<typename T>
class ColumnDef : public Base
{
public:
    ColumnDef(void) {}

    template<typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T>::value>>
    bool toValue(int *p) override
    {
        std::cout << "Signed" << std::endl;

        return true;
    }

    template<typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>>
    bool toValue(int *p) override
    {
        std::cout << "Unsigned" << std::endl;

        return true;
    }
};


#endif /* SIGNED_TEMPLATE_H_ */
```

Comment: Looks like a bad mixture of static and dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: @tobi303, copy &paste error fixed.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427667/sfinae-working-in-return-type-but-not-as-template-parameter) explains the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your override is wrong...
You have to forward your call, something like:

```
template<typename T>
class ColumnDef : public Base
{
public:
    ColumnDef() {}

    bool toValue(int *p) override
    {
        return toValueImpl(p, std::is_unsigned<T>{});
    }

private:
    bool toValueImpl(int *p, std::true_type)
    {
        std::cout << "Signed" << std::endl;

        return true;
    }

    bool toValueImpl(int *p, std::false_type)
    {
        std::cout << "Unsigned" << std::endl;

        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: It works in gcc, but in VS2010 I get errors i,e. `error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'` on the line `return toValueImpl(p, std::is_unsigned<T>{});`

Comment: Use `std::is_unsigned<T>()` instead before C++11.

Comment: Had to use `std::is_signed<T>::type()` in VS2010, just noticed Jarod42's comment which also works.

Comment: maybe you could edit your answer adding information why OP overriding is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix dynamic and static polymorphism, virtual functions can not be template.

The answer of Jarod42 is probably simpler, but just to demonstrate how you could use enable_if in this case:

```
class ColumnDef : public Base
{
public:
    ColumnDef(void) {}

    bool toValue(int *p)override
    {
        return toValueImpl<T>(p);
    }
private:
    template<typename T1>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T1>::value,bool>::type toValueImpl(int *p)
    {
        std::cout << "Signed" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }

    template<typename T1>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T1>::value,bool>::type toValueImpl(int *p)
    {
        std::cout << "Unsigned" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how the return type is determined of the helper function? Or does it always have to be bool. Or would I have to replace the `value, bool>` part with my other type if this were the case? I have found only examples using bool, so I'm unsure abou the usage of this template thingy.

Comment: The return type can be any type, it is determined by the second template argument of enable_if. In this case it is bool, but you can replace bool by another type.