# Using std::enable_if with anonymous type parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I try to use `std::enable_if` with an unused and unnamed type parameter, in order to not distort the `return` type. However, the following code does not compile.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral<T>::value>>
T foo() { std::cout << "non-integral" << std::endl; return T(); }

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
T foo() { std::cout << "integral" << std::endl; return T(); }

int main() {
  foo<float>();
  foo<int>();
}
```

The compiler says:

```
7:3: error: redefinition of 'template<class T, class> T foo()'
4:3: note: 'template<class T, class> T foo()' previously declared here
 In function 'int main()':
11:12: error: no matching function for call to 'foo()'
11:12: note: candidate is:
4:3: note: template<class T, class> T foo()
4:3: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

What is the problem here? How do I have to change the code to get it compile? The text book "Discovering Modern C++" explicitly encourages the use of `std::enable_if` with anonymous type parameters.

EDIT: I know that it works if I put `std::enable_if` into the return type. However, my intention is to get some more details why it does not work if I use it with anonymous type parameters. As I said, my text book encourages the variant using anonymous type parameters, so I am wondering why my code does not compile.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `std::enable_if` into the return type?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427667/sfinae-working-in-return-type-but-not-as-template-parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, my intention is to get some more details why it does not work if I use it with anonymous type parameters.

Default values do not participate in overload resolution, thus you are actually redefining the same function.

Let's simplify your example:

```
template<typename = int>
void f() {}

template<typename = void>
void f() {}

int main() {
    f<>();
}
```

The code above does not compile, for it couldn't know what version of `f` you want to invoke.

In your case, if I invoke `foo` as `foo<void, void>`, I've almost the same problem.
The compiler cannot guess what's my intention and the fact that the second parameter has a default value doesn't mean that you can't pass in a different type.

Because of that, the code is ill-formed and the compiler correctly gives you an error.

---

As a side note, you can still have it working without using the `std::enable_if_t` in the return type.
As an example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral<T>::value>* = nullptr>
T foo() { std::cout << "non-integral" << std::endl; return T(); }

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>* = nullptr>
T foo() { std::cout << "integral" << std::endl; return T(); }

int main() {
    foo<float>();
    foo<int>();
}
```

---

While I tried to figure out what was the (wrong) assumption of the OP and explain why it can be the case, @T.C. correctly pointed the attention out to the actual reason in the comments to this answer.
It's worth to quote his comment to add more details to the answer:

> It's not overload resolution; it's declaration matching. There are no two overloads in the first place for any ambiguity to arise. It's two redefinition errors: the function template, and the default template argument.

Comment: Forget about the invocation; the problem is that you are redefining the same function template.

Comment: @T.C. I said that in the first line. The invokation was another example of how it could create problems if allowed. Should I remove it from the answer?

Comment: It's not overload resolution; it's declaration matching. There are no two overloads in the first place for any ambiguity to arise. It's two redefinition errors: the function template, and the default template argument.

Comment: @T.C. I see your point and I'm not saying you are wrong (well, I think I'll never say you are wrong actually - skills gap is evident), but I tried to find out the wrong reasoning of the OP that was (in my humble opinion) that default values to template parameters participate in overload resolution. That's all. If you agree, I'm integrating the answer with your comment to give more details.

Answer (score 5):

You can put `enable_if` into the return type:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral<T>::value,T>
foo() { std::cout << "non-integral" << std::endl; return T(); }

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>
foo() { std::cout << "integral" << std::endl; return T(); }
```

By the way, `enable_if_t` is available from C++14, so you might want to say `typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type` instead. Quite a mouthful.

But a little more idiomatic (and readable) would be to dispatch basing on the type:

```
template <typename T>
T foo_impl(std::false_type) { std::cout << "non-integral" << std::endl; return T(); }

template <typename T>
T foo_impl(std::true_type) { std::cout << "integral" << std::endl; return T(); }

template <typename T>
T foo(){
    return foo_impl<T>(typename std::is_integral<T>::type{});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you can SFINAE away functions. You should usually refrain from adding an extra function/template parameter and just mingle with the return type.

```
template <typename T>
auto foo() -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral<T>::value, T>
{ std::cout << "non-integral" << std::endl; return T(); }

template <typename T>
auto foo() -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>
{ std::cout << "integral" << std::endl; return T(); }
```

Comment: I know that it works if I put `std::enable_if` into the return type. However, my intention is to get some more details why it does not work if I use it with anonymous type parameters. As I said, my text book encourages the variant using anonymous type parameters, so I am wondering why my code does not compile. It seems that you encourage the opposite. What are the reasons?

Comment: @user1494080 I encourage the opposite, because adding extra template parameters or extra function parameters like in the answer above can allow the user to do this: `foo<float, int>();` or `foo<float>(nullptr);` We don't want that to be allowed. It can break stuff. Plus you rarely can go wrong with return type SFINAE.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is that you're using `enable_if_t` on the right of the equal sign.

You have to use it on the left

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral<T>::value, int> = 0>
T foo() { std::cout << "non-integral" << std::endl; return T(); }

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, int> = 0>
T foo() { std::cout << "integral" << std::endl; return T(); }

int main() {
  foo<float>();
  foo<int>();
}
```

But this work with C++14.

In C++11 (your question is tagged C++11) you don't have `enable_if_t`.

The code become

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T,
          typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
T foo() { std::cout << "non-integral" << std::endl; return T(); }

template <typename T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
T foo() { std::cout << "integral" << std::endl; return T(); }

int main() {
  foo<float>();
  foo<int>();
}
```

Comment: "You have to use it on the left" <-- that's simply not true.

Comment: @Barry - sorry: not sure to understand: with it's "not true" do you mean that he can use `std::enable_if_t` in other ways (by example: to enable (or not) the return value)?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you can, in fact, use `enable_if_t` as a default type (just like you can use any other type). The error here is that OP is trying to provide *two different* default types for the *same* function template.

Comment: @Barry - I try to say it with my word (please, correct me if I'm wrong). The OP define two versions of `f()` with the same template signature (`typename`, `typename`); this give an error because the sfinae can give different default values to the second `typename` argument but can't change the signature; this give a collision, the compiler can't choose and give error. In my example, sfinae enable, or not, the second `typename` parameter so change (or not) the function template signature; so the compiler see a single `f()` (for every invocation) and compile without error.