# SFINAE applied to iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, sfinae

I'm writing a template function that should only accept random access iterator of any container containing a specific type (defined by template ).
At the moment, I'm first trying to limit the type of the iterator using SFINAE but the code does not compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename It,
         std::enable_if<
             std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category,
                          std::random_access_iterator_tag>::value,
             typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type>>
void func(const It& begin, const It& end)
{
    std::cout << begin[0] << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    func(a.begin(), a.end());
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
error: ‘struct std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename
std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category,std::random_access_iterator_tag::value,
typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type>’ is not a
valid type for a template non-type parameter template<typename It,
std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits

error: no matching function for call to
‘func(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator)’
func(a.begin(), a.end());
```

Comment: FYI you wrote the equivalent of `template<typename T, Z<...>>` which won't compile since `Z<...>` isn't a valid type for non-type template parameter

Answer (score 1):

I can't parse your `enable_if`.
That works:

```
template<typename It, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::value, int>::type = 0>
void func(const It& begin, const It& end)
{
    std::cout << begin[0] << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    func(a.begin(), a.end());
    return 0;
}
```

But it can be that I misunderstood your intention.

Comment: Thank you. And How could I edit your answer in order to be sure that the iterator is only on a container of std::string for example ?

Comment: You can use && in the condition of enable if and to add other condition that checks that the  std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type (with const volatile removed) is std::string

Answer (score 1):

You need `typename =` to use an anonymous type for SFINAE like that:

```
template<typename It,
         typename = std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category,
                                                std::random_access_iterator_tag>::value,
                                   typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type>>
void func(const It& begin, const It& end)
{
    std::cout << begin[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Or, you could use `std::enable_if<...>::type` as a return type for your function.

If you're working in C++17 or later, consider looking into the Concepts proposal that's making its way into C++20.

Comment: Thank you. And How could I edit your answer if I want to also check the type of elements in the container ?

Comment: That sounds like a new question - if you ask it, remember to be specific about what kind of constraint you need on the type.  Oh, and you're encouraged to up-vote any answers that are helpful to you.

Comment: Your sfinae will be broken when you overload `func` for another iterator type. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/40250368/4832499. On the other hand, putting it in the return type will work.

Comment: @PasserBy - no, it's fine (different `It`).  But your linked question is certainly worth reading to get a better understanding of what does and doesn't work.