# Why does SFINAE not work with std::enable_if_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, template-templates

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

template
<
    typename T,
    template<typename, typename = std::allocator<T>> class C,
    typename = std::enable_if_t
    <
    std::is_same<std::vector<T>, C<T>>::value
    >
>
void f(const C<T>& coll)
{
    std::cout << "vector" << std::endl;
}

template
<
    typename T,
    template<typename, typename = std::allocator<T>> class C,
    typename = std::enable_if_t
    <
    std::is_same<std::list<T>, C<T>>::value
    >
>
void f(const C<T>& coll)
{
    std::cout << "list" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
        std::vector<int> c1{ 1, 2, 3 };
        std::list<int> c2{ 1, 2, 3 };       
        f(c1);
        f(c2);
}
```

Clang 3.8 complains:

> error : template parameter redefines default argument: typename = std::enable_if_t

What's wrong in the code?

Comment: Have you tried to use non-type template parameter instead, like `enable_if_t<condition>* = nullptr`?

Comment: I have tried that, but the result is same.

Comment: I think it should work with non-type template parameter. This code is ill-formed

Comment: You need to have generic implementation and specialize for container type

Comment: Oh one more thing `std::enable_if_t` is available since c++14

Comment: The sfinae should look than more like `typename enable_if<condition>::type* = nullptr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need SFINAE? A simple overload is enough!

```
template <typename T>
void f(const std::vector<T>& coll)
{
    std::cout << "vector" << std::endl;
}

template < typename T>
void f(const std::list<T>& coll)
{
    std::cout << "list" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> c1{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::list<int> c2{ 1, 2, 3 };
    f(c1);
    f(c2);
}
```

And if you really want to use SFINAE ( with no sense in that case ) you can fix your definition with:

```
template
<   
typename T,
         template<typename, typename = std::allocator<T>> class C,
         typename std::enable_if_t
         <
         std::is_same<std::list<T>, C<T>>::value
         >* = nullptr
    >
void f(const C<T>& coll);
```

And why your definition did not work can be found already here:
[SFINAE working in return type but not as template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427667/sfinae-working-in-return-type-but-not-as-template-parameter)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question _why doesn't it work?_

Comment: @skypjack: Fixed that. Thanks! So I mark that also as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Default template parameters don't participate in function matching.
From the point of view of the compiler, when it's trying to look for a suitable function, both have the following signature:

```
template <typename T, template<typename, typename> class C, typename>
void f(const C<T>& coll);
```

Because of that, the second definition of `f` is actually a redefinition.

Consider a minimal example:

```
template<typename = void>
void f() {}

template<typename = char>
void f() {}

// ...

f<>();
```

How could the compiler figure out what `f` you want to invoke?
More or less the same happens in your code.

Move the `enable_if_t` to the return type and it will work as expected.
In this case, substitution will exclude one of the two definition because of an error (as expected from a sfinae expression).

Comment: One not always can move `enable_if_t` to the return type (constructor/conversion operator) on the other hand since c++11 always can use non-type template parameter with default value this is why I prefer this one but I like your explanation very much so +1

Comment: @W.F. I see your point. In this case, the return type is a viable solution and that's why I mentioned it. That's all. ;-)