# enable_if to check if value type of iterator is a pair

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to write a specialised template function for iterators whose value type is a pair. My expectation is that this should match iterators of std::map.

In order to detect the pair:

```
template <typename>
struct is_pair : std::false_type
{ };

template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_pair<std::pair<T, U>> : std::true_type
{ };

// also tried this, but it didn't help
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_pair<std::pair<const T, U>> : std::true_type
{ };
```

Then i use enable_if in the function declaration:

```
template<class ITR>
decltype(auto) do_stuff(
        std::enable_if<is_pair<typename ITR::value_type>::value, ITR> itr) {
    //access of itr->second ok.
}
```

However, when i use this function with a map iterator I get the following error messages from clang (Xcode 8.3):

> Candidate template ignored: could not match 'enable_if' against '__map_iterator'

With no further explanation why enable if didn't match.

When inspecting the type of __map_iterator, it looks like it should match is_pair check.

Comment: I *think* a map iterator (after deref) is a *reference* to a pair, not just a value-type. Pretty sure you'll have to strip the reference to make this fly (or account for it via another specialize; haven't given it a ton of thought.

Answer (score 6):

It's better to move `std::enable_if` to another default template argument, like so:

```
template<class ITR, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_pair<typename ITR::value_type>::value, ITR>::type>
decltype(auto) do_stuff(ITR && itr) {
    //access of itr->second ok.
}
```

This will not block argument deduction, since `ITR && itr` is now an universal reference.

Full example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

template <typename>
struct is_pair : std::false_type
{ };

template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_pair<std::pair<T, U>> : std::true_type
{ };


template<class ITR, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_pair<typename ITR::value_type>::value, ITR>::type>
decltype(auto) do_stuff(ITR && itr) {
    //access of itr->second ok.
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> foo{
        { 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4 },
    };

    do_stuff(foo.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

---

[Live on gcc.godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/ud5kg4)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, essentially it was: [SFINAE working in return type but not as template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427667/sfinae-working-in-return-type-but-not-as-template-parameter)

So in the end i used this signature:

```
template<class ITR>
typename std::enable_if_t<is_pair<typename ITR::value_type>::value, ITR>::value_type::second_type& get_value_from_iterator(ITR itr)
```

The reference was required because i needed an actual reference to the value inside the map.

The const version of the check wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I used code similar to what GreenScape proposed, but I made a small adjustment.

I changed

```
template<class ITR, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_pair<typename ITR::value_type>::value, ITR>::type>
```

into

```
template<class ITR, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_pair<typename std::iterator_traits<ITR>::value_type>::value, ITR>::type>
```

Using this, not only std::vector works, but also std::array.