# Move SFINAE condition to the left-most for readability

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae, readability, enable-if

[Default template arguments are not considered when compiler judges whether there are some duplicate overload function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427667/sfinae-working-in-return-type-but-not-as-template-parameter)

This totally ruins my fun, while I try to push every dirty thing to left-most.

Here is an example.
Although the below code is not compilable, it is relatively beautiful and easy to read :-

```
template<bool enable= a&& b>  typename std::enable_if_t<enable,void> f(){}
template<bool enable= a&&!b>  typename std::enable_if_t<enable,void> f(){}
template<bool enable=!a&& b>  typename std::enable_if_t<enable,void> f(){}
template<bool enable=!a&&!b>  typename std::enable_if_t<enable,void> f(){}
                                                             //^ so neat
look like : if(enable){instantiate static f(){}} ... so intuitive!
```

... compared to a compilable one :-

```
template<bool a1=a,bool b1=b> typename std::enable_if_t< a1&& b1,void> f(){}
template<bool a1=a,bool b1=b> typename std::enable_if_t< a1&&!b1,void> f(){}
template<bool a1=a,bool b1=b> typename std::enable_if_t<!a1&& b1,void> f(){}
template<bool a1=a,bool b1=b> typename std::enable_if_t<!a1&&!b1,void> f(){}
          ^ two temp "type"  ----> scroll ------->      ^ deep hidden logic
```

It may seem to be a trivial problem, but it reoccurs to me in many files.
It makes me nervous. I start to code SFINAE with fear.

Are there some ways to make it works and still be concise and intuitive?
Here is **[coliru demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f78560683ec7e8f).**

**Edit:** Here is an example that is more similar to the real world case (beautiful-but-wrong version):-

```
template<class X,class A,class B,class C,class D>class Database{
    public: static constexpr bool hasC=typename X::hasC;             
    public: static constexpr bool hasD=typename X::hasD;    
    /** some complex field (NOT depend on "hasC" and "hasD") */    
    public: template<bool enable=!hasC&&!hasD>      
      std::enable_if_t<enable,void> add(A a,B b){    
         /**some complex */
    }
    public: template<bool enable=hasC&&!hasD>      
      std::enable_if_t<enable,void> add(A a,B b,C c){    
         /**some complex */
    }
    public: template<bool enable=!hasC&&hasD>      
      std::enable_if_t<enable,void> add(A a,B b,D d){    
         /**some complex */
    }
    public: template<bool enable=hasC&&hasD>      
      std::enable_if_t<enable,void> add(A a,B b,C c,D d){    
         /**some complex */
    }
};
```

Comment: I believe you are misusing SFINAE. It should be used to disable different overloads. On the other hand we have *specializations* which are better suited in this case.

Comment: @DeiDei  Do you mean specialization at class level, e.g. `template<....>class Test<....>{}`?   If so, I think I can't, because I use SNIFAE to avoid code duplication inside a very-similar class. (not sure)

Comment: @javaLover Show us what you really want to do, not how you are trying to achieve it - I don't see why you would not be able to use specialization here.

Comment: @Holt Thank, I edited my question to show more real example.

Comment: Do you use template arguments `C` and `D` when `X` has neither? Does the rest of the class depend on `A` - `D`? My guess is that you could have a top class with only `A` and `B` and then specialize the class depending on `X` to have different `add`.

Comment: @Holt Around 30% still depends on `C` and `D`.    Yes, I agree I can specialize it.  The disadvantage of such approach is that different version "add" will be far from each other (i.e. far-away lines / files), so it may cause maintainability problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that until you get [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) with C++17, the most legible way to do this is with tagged dispatch:

```
template<bool a,bool b>
class Test{
public:
    void f()
    {
        fhelp(f_tag<>{});
    }
private:
    template<bool = a, bool = b>
    struct f_tag{};

    void  fhelp(f_tag<true, true>){}
    void  fhelp(f_tag<true, false>){}
    void  fhelp(f_tag<false, true>){}
    void  fhelp(f_tag<false, false>){}
};
```

That way we can be more explicit about what the expected values of `a` and `b` are. This works well especially since your conditionals are all `&&`. It's also more obvious to the naked eye that no two overloads are the same.

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YdrqP7pu8tVCXUzd)

---

#### Edit

The C++17 version would have us write our `f()` like so:

```
void f()
{
    if constexpr (a && b)
    {
         // ...
    }
    if constexpr (a && !b)
    {
        // ...
    }
    if constexpr (!a && b)
    {
        // ...
    }
    if constexpr (!a && !b)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In fact this may not be very legible after all. Personally I still prefer the tagged dispatch approach.

---

#### Edit2:

Regarding your "real-world" example where the functions have different parameters, you may start to consider specializing the class instead. However, you can still accomplish what you need with tag dispatch. The public-facing function needs to become a variadic template, while the helper functions retain their true types, so you're still safe:

```
public: 
    template<bool = X::hasC, bool = X::hasD>
    struct add_tag{};

    template<class... T>
    void add(T&&... args)
    {
        add_help(add_tag<>{}, std::forward<T>(args)...);
    }

private:
    void add_help(add_tag<false, false>, A a, B b)
    {/*..*/}
    void add_help(add_tag<true, false>, A a, B b, C c)
    {/*..*/}
    void add_help(add_tag<false, true>, A a, B b, D d)
    {/*..*/}
    void add_help(add_tag<true, true>, A a, B b, C c, D d)
    {/*..*/}
```

#### [Demo2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HsSTnCZ60OmieGs5)

Comment: Thank for the big demo!   Do you happen to know workaround about the last part of question i.e. when those functions actually received different parameter?

Comment: @javaLover: From what I can tell, you probably want to specialize the class rather than the functions for that last example. Also, remove the `typename` for the `constexpr` booleans if you're trying to reference another class' `static constexpr bool`

Comment: @javaLover: [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Jnuhby6MsgADhnZP) is the tag dispatch approach applied to your example with different parameters.

Comment: After I praise your solution silently, I found that intellisense will no longer work for `add()`.  Thus, in real life, I will stick with my old solution.  Because of the beauty of your solution, I can't really resist to press accept though.  Thank.