# Template specialization for fundamental types

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, generic-programming

Is there any way to make a template specialization for fundamental types only?
I have tried to do the following:

```
template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type>
class foo
{
}

template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type>
class foo
{
}
```

But I'm getting an error that the template is already defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SFINAE working in return type but not as template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427667/sfinae-working-in-return-type-but-not-as-template-parameter)

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Not a dup; that one is dealing with functions, this one with classes

Comment: @Justin but the principle should be the same, right?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Not at all.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan They are the same except for partial specialization, which is not allowed for functions.

Answer (score 15):

Here you are creating two templated classes with the same name, not specializations.

You need to create a generic one and then specialize it:

```
// not specialized template (for non-fundamental types), Enabler will 
// be used to specialize for fundamental types
template <class T, class Enabler = void>
class foo { };

// specialization for fundamental types
template <class T>
class foo<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>> { };
```

Comment: Do you *really* need to specialize for `!is_fundamental`? You can just use the primary template.

Comment: I am using the primary template for shared_ptrs, I'm building a pattern for storing lockfree values.

Comment: @Rakete1111 No, it makes no sense here, I just went on with OP's code. I have updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe What Rakete1111 means is that you can use a non-specialized template for non-fundamental types, and a specialized one for fundamental ones. You don't need to specialize for both, see my updated answer.