# Template type derivation

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization, template-argument-deduction

I need to implement a class, say 'MyClass' using templates.

```
template<class T>
class MyClass
{
public:


          T var1;
          T1 var2;
        };
```

There are two member variables var1 and var2. If the class template argument, 'T', is fundamental type (eg: float, double or long double), the types of both the variables var1 and var2 should be the same as the template argument. That is T1 = T in the above example.

But if the template argument is `std::complex<T>`, I would like to have

```
T var1;
std::complex<T> var2;
```

How to implement it in C++11?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a partial specialization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template specialization for fundamental types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244809/template-specialization-for-fundamental-types)

Comment: What if it's neither arithmetic or `std::complex`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution could be define a simple type traits to extract the correct type

```
template <typename T>
struct myTypeTraits
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct myTypeTraits<std::complex<T>>
 { using type = T; };
```

and `MyClass` become

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
 {
   using T0 = typename myTypeTraits<T>::type;

   T0 var1;
   T  var2;
 };
```

If you want to be sure that `T` is a fundamental type (or do you mean arithmetic?), is a little more complicated.

A possible way is define a type traits to say (`true` or `false`) if a type is a `std::complex`

```
template <typename>
struct isComplex : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T>
struct isComplex<std::complex<T>> : public std::true_type
 { };
```

Next modify `myTypeTraits` with a declaration (no generic definition) and **two** default bool values

```
template <typename T, bool = std::is_fundamental<T>::value, 
                      bool = isComplex<T>::value>
struct myTypeTraits;
```

Next two specializations, the first one for fundamentals and the second one for complexes types

```
template <typename T>
struct myTypeTraits<T, true, false>
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct myTypeTraits<std::complex<T>, false, true>
 { using type = T; };
```

The `MyClass` class remain equals but now give an error if you try to instantiate it with (by example) a `std::string`.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
struct isComplex : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T>
struct isComplex<std::complex<T>> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename T, bool = std::is_fundamental<T>::value, 
                      bool = isComplex<T>::value>
struct myTypeTraits;

template <typename T>
struct myTypeTraits<T, true, false>
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct myTypeTraits<std::complex<T>, false, true>
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
class MyClass
 {
   public:  // public to check with the static_assert()
      using T0 = typename myTypeTraits<T>::type;

   private:
      T0 var1;
      T  var2;
 };

int main ()
 {
   MyClass<int>                  mi; // compile
   MyClass<std::complex<float>>  mc; // compile
   // MyClass<std::string>          ms; // compilation error

   static_assert( std::is_same<int, decltype(mi)::T0>{}, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<float, decltype(mc)::T0>{}, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the answer. However, I just realized that I should have member functions which again depends on the template parameters. Can you please provide and elegant solution for this too?

Comment: @Soo - if you have a lot of differences, you should consider to partial specialize the entire `MyClass` (as suggested by Quentin); but if you want a help for "member functions which again depends on the template parameters", sorry but it's too generic; I suggest you to modify the question, with a specific example, or ask it in another question.