# Template type deduction for member variables and function arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following implementation of a template class:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    void setVar1(const T& v1)
    {
        var1 = v1;
    }
    void setVar2(const T1& v2)
    {
        var2 = v2;
    }

    T var1;        
    T1 var2;
};
```

If the template parameter `T` is a fundamental type (like `float`, `double`, or `long double`) I would like to have `T1 = T`.

If the template parameter `T` is `std::complex<float>`, I would like to have `T=std::complex<float>` and `T1 = float`. Similarly for `std::complex<double>` and `std::complex<long double>`.

Deducing the type of the variable is discussed at [Template type derivation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334675/template-type-derivation)

However, the additional member functions prevents usage of their solution in this context.

Comment: If you just add `using T1 = typename myTypeTraits<T>::type;` before the member functions, that solution ought to work. What problems have you seen?

Comment: An internal (and private) traits class with a specialization for template-template arguments seems like it could be a way to a solution.

Comment: A [possible solution](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JjVdJ3kuLzKrpeg0), I'm sure there are easier way though

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks for your valuable comment. I have posted an answer to my question with the help of your comment. I have also reported a problem related to it. Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: @BoPersson The problem I mentioned has been now posted as a question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47356284/template-type-deduction-in-function-return-type

Answer (score 0):

A custom traits class would suffice. You can leverage partial specializations to select the type you want/need. Example code

```
template<typename T, bool F> class Base;

template<typename T>
class Base <T, true> {
public:
  T var2;
};

template<typename T>
class Base <std::complex<T>, false> {
public:
  typename std::complex<T>::value_type var2;
};

template <typename T>
class BaseHelper : public Base<T, std::is_fundamental<T>::value> {};

template<class T>
class MyClass : public BaseHelper<T> {
public:

  using T1 = decltype(BaseHelper<T>::var2);

  void setVar1(const T& v1) {
    var1 = v1;
  }
  void setVar2(const T1& v2) {
    this->var2 = v2;
  }

  T var1;
};
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JjVdJ3kuLzKrpeg0)</kbd>

There are many other ways though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Bo Personns comment and the answer provided at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334675/template-type-derivation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47356284/template-type-deduction-in-function-return-type)

I got the following working example.

The content of my .h file is as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <typeinfo>


template <typename T>
class MyClass
 {


 template <typename T0>
struct myTypeTraits
 { using type = T0; };

template <typename T0>
struct myTypeTraits<std::complex<T0>>
 { using type = T0; };


public:

   using T0 = typename myTypeTraits<T>::type;

   void setVar1(const T0& v);

   void setVar2(const T& v);


T getVar2() const;




   void print() const;

   T0 var1;
   T  var2;
 };
```

The .cpp file contains the following lines of code.

```
template <class T>
void MyClass<T>::setVar1(const T0& v)
{
    var1 = v;
}


template <class T>
void MyClass<T>::setVar2(const T& v)
{
    var2 = v;
}



template <class T>
T MyClass<T>::getVar2() const
{
    return var2;
}


template <typename T>
void MyClass<T>::print() const
{
    std::cout<<"var1: "<<var1<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"var2: "<<var2<<std::endl;

}



int main()
{

    MyClass<float> tmp;

    MyClass<std::complex<float> > tmp1;

    tmp.print();
    tmp1.print();
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works as intended.

However, I have another related question posted at [Template type deduction in function return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47356284/template-type-deduction-in-function-return-type)