# Template type deduction in function return type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction

This is in continuation with the question posted at [Template type deduction for member variables and function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346826/template-type-deduction-for-member-variables-and-function-arguments/47355739#47355739)

My .h file contains the following lines.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <typeinfo>


template <typename T>
class MyClass
 {


 template <typename T0>
struct myTypeTraits
 { using type = T0; };

template <typename T0>
struct myTypeTraits<std::complex<T0>>
 { using type = T0; };


public:

   using T0 = typename myTypeTraits<T>::type;

   void setVar1(const T0& v);

   void setVar2(const T& v);

 T0 getVar1() const;
T getVar2() const;




   void print() const;

   T0 var1;
   T  var2;
 };
```

The .cpp file has the following codes.

```
#include "tmp.h"
template <class T>
void MyClass<T>::setVar1(const T0& v)
{
    var1 = v;
}


template <class T>
void MyClass<T>::setVar2(const T& v)
{
    var2 = v;
}


template <class T>
T0 MyClass<T>::getVar1() const
{
    return var1;
}


template <class T>
T MyClass<T>::getVar2() const
{
    return var2;
}


template <typename T>
void MyClass<T>::print() const
{
    std::cout<<"var1: "<<var1<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"var2: "<<var2<<std::endl;

}



int main()
{

    MyClass<float> tmp;

    MyClass<std::complex<float> > tmp1;

    tmp.print();
    tmp1.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I compile the code using C++ 11 support in g++, I get the following error.

```
tmp.cpp:17:1: error: ‘T0’ does not name a type
 T0 MyClass<T>::getVar1() const
 ^
```

How can I remove the error?

Comment: *"The .cpp file has the following codes."*: -> See [why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler can't know that `T0` is defined in `MyClass<T>`. So you need to properly qualify the reutrn type:

```
template <class T>
typename MyClass<T>::T0 MyClass<T>::getVar1() const {
  return var1;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a trailing return type, which you won't need to qualify either:

```
template <class T>
auto MyClass<T>::getVar1() const -> T0 {
  return var1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
// ......................vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
void MyClass<T>::setVar1(typename MyClass<T>::T0 const & v)
{
    var1 = v;
}
```

and the same for `getVar1()`

Comment: While certainly allowed, this is not strictly  necessary for `setVar1`, because the compiler can find `T0` being defined in `MyClass<T>` at that point.