# SFINAE works as return type, but not parameter type

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I was trying to use `enable_if` to avoid duplicating code. It works fine as long as placed in the return type, but not if it's in the parameters. Before this gets closed as a dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427667/sfinae-working-in-return-type-but-not-as-template-parameter), the error I'm getting is not a redefinition, but a "no matching function for call." Here's my MCVE (not so "C", or so "M" for that matter) using VS2015 and g++ 7.2.0 (mingw):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>


template <typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
class Matrix
{
public:
    static const size_t ROWS = M;
    static const size_t COLS = N;
    typedef T SCALAR;

    SCALAR operator[](const size_t index) const
    {
        static_assert((COLS == 1 || ROWS == 1), "operator[] is only for vectors (single row or column).");
        return m_elements.at(index);
    }

    SCALAR& operator[](const size_t index)
    {
        static_assert((COLS == 1 || ROWS == 1), "operator[] is only for vectors (single row or column).");
        return m_elements.at(index);
    }

    std::array<T, M * N> m_elements;
};

template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
static inline T Length(
    const Matrix<typename std::enable_if<(M == 1 || N == 1), T>::type, N, M> & input)
{
    T value = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::max(N, M); ++i)
    {
        value += (input[i] * input[i]);
    }
    return std::sqrt(value);
}

template <typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
static inline 
Matrix<typename std::enable_if<(M == 3 && N == 1) || (M == 1 && N == 3), T>::type , M, N>
CrossProduct(const Matrix<T, M, N> & a, const Matrix<T, M, N> & b)
{
    Matrix<T, M, N> result;
    result[0] = a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1];
    result[1] = a[2] * b[0] - a[0] * b[2];
    result[2] = a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0];
    return result;
}


Matrix<double, 1, 1> m11;
Matrix<double, 3, 1> m31;
Matrix<double, 1, 3> m13;
Matrix<double, 3, 3> m33;


auto l0 = Length(m11);  // Should work, but doesn't: no matching function for call to 'Length(Matrix<double, 1, 1>&)'
auto l1 = Length(m31);  // Should work, but doesn't: no matching function for call to 'Length(Matrix<double, 3, 1>&)'
auto l2 = Length(m13);  // Should work, but doesn't: no matching function for call to 'Length(Matrix<double, 1, 3>&)'
//auto l3 = Length(m33);    // Shouldn't work, and doesn't: no matching function for call to 'Length(Matrix<double, 3, 3>&)'

auto v1 = CrossProduct(m13, m13); //Works, as expected
//auto v2 = CrossProduct(m11, m11); // As expected: enable_if.cpp:71:32: error: no matching function for
                                    // call to 'CrossProduct(Matrix<double, 1, 1>&, Matrix<double, 1, 1>&)'
```

If I change the signature of `Length` to

```
static inline typename std::enable_if<(M == 1 || N == 1), T>::type \
Length(const math::Matrix<T, N, M> & input)
```

it works fine. But the error it gives me seems to indicate that it was able to determine the correct signature (e.g. `Length(Matrix<double, 3, 1>&)`).

Why is the compiler unable to find a matching function if the `enable_if` is in the parameter list, but is able to if it's in the return type?

Comment: you may take a look at [what-is-a-nondeduced-context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context/25245676#25245676)

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Why are the `int`s not deducible? Based on the error, I would think that the compiler deduced it very well.

Comment: the int's are deducible, T is not, because it appears in a non-deduced context (ie std::enable_if<>::type)

Comment: Is this what you want? https://ideone.com/2h0ZHl

Comment: @KillzoneKid Yes, that works as well (so does `template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M, typename Dummy = typename std::enable_if<(M == 1 || N == 1), T>::type>`). But if my example in the parenthesis works, I don't see why it doesn't when in the parameter list. In both cases the compiler had to deduce the type of `T`.

Comment: @AviGinsburg: Yes but what Massimiliano has been trying to say is that in the case it doesn't work, you have made it so that `T` is in a non deduced context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::enable_if<..., T>::type` is a nested name, and as such cannot be deduced:

See [[temp.deduct.type]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.deduct.type#5.1):

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> —
>       The *nested-name-specifier* of a type that was specified using a *qualified-id*.
>
> . . .

As a workaround, move the `enable_if` to a separate template argument:

```
template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M, typename std::enable_if<(M == 1 || N == 1), int>::type = 0>
static inline T Length(
    const Matrix<T, N, M> & input)
```

Comment: I'd avoid the `void*` stuff for now, whether it is legal or not has been up for debate. There's a defect report for it around here somewhere. Better to just make it an `int = 0` or something. Edit: Here: https://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#175

Comment: The link is to the current draft, yes? Is it different for e.g. c++11?

Comment: @AndyG - updated, thanks. AviGinsburg - this basic rule has always been there, as far as I know.

Comment: *In other words, anything that contains :: cannot be deduced.* Unless that `::` is part of a poiner-to-member declaration ;)