# restrict function pointer member template to only derived classes

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, member

I'm trying to limit template deduction only to objects from the same hierarchy.

The code below compiles

```
template<class T>
void RegisterAction(const string& actionId, bool(T::*f)())
{
    m_actions.emplace(actionId, std::bind(f, static_cast<T*>(this)));
}
```

but this code doesn't

```
template<class T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value>>
void RegisterAction(const string& actionId, bool(T::*f)())
{
    m_actions.emplace(actionId, std::bind(f, static_cast<T*>(this)));
}
```

m_actions is of type `std::unordered_map<string, std::function<bool()>>`

Here is the error from Visual Studio

```
'BaseClass::RegisterAction': no matching overloaded function found
error C2783: 'void BaseClass::RegisterAction(const string &,bool (__cdecl T::* )(void))': could not deduce template argument for '__formal'
```

This is how you would use the method:

```
void DerivedClass::InitActions()
{
    RegisterAction("general.copy", &DerivedClass::OnCopy);
    RegisterAction("general.paste", &DerivedClass::OnPaste);
}
```

Btw, I can't use `static_assert` because there I'm using c++14.

Doesn't anyone has any idea?

Comment: How are you calling `RegisterAction`? [mcve] please.

Comment: `template<class T, typename std::enable_if_t<...>>` will never be selected. You either need `template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<...>>` or something like `template<class T, std::enable_if_t<..., int> = 0>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to introduce a new template parameter in order to cause a substitution error---which is correct---but your syntax is slightly incorrect. What you should write is:

```
template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value>>
                       // ^^^ this equal sign is crucial
```

When you write `typename = foo`, you're declaring an unnamed type template parameter (it's like writing `typename unused = foo`) and making the default value for that type `foo`. Thus, if someone tries to instantiate this template with `T` not derived from `BaseClass`, a substitution failure occurs in the default argument, causing deduction to fail.

Since you wrote it without the equal sign, `typename std::enable_if_t<...>` was interpreted as a *typename-specifier*, that is, the compiler thinks you're declaring a *non-type* template parameter whose type is `typename std::enable_if_t<...>`, which you have left unnamed. Consequently, when `T` is derived from `BaseClass`, the type of this template parameter is `void`. Since non-type template parameters cannot have type `void` (as there are no values of type `void`), a SFINAE error occurs here.

Interestingly, both GCC and Clang *also* [fail to give a useful error message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/911cc234174e9b2f). They also complain that the unnamed template argument cannot be deduced, rather than pointing out that `void` non-type template parameters are invalid (or even just pointing out that it *is* a non-type template parameter of type `void`).

Comment: FWIW, [using a default template type argument comes with it's own problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427667/sfinae-working-in-return-type-but-not-as-template-parameter).  They can use `template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value, bool> = true>` instead to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When it is intended to use RegisterAction to register only for those classes that are derived from BaseClass, is seems that it is better to state with static_assert explicitly why some T cannot be used with RegisterAction instead of just "hiding" the problem with SFINAE.

So

```
template<class T>
void RegisterAction(const string& actionId, bool(T::*f)())
{
    static_assert(
        std::is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value,
        "T shall be derived from BaseClass for RegisterAction to work"
    );
    m_actions.emplace(actionId, std::bind(f, static_cast<T*>(this)));
}
```

will scream loudly and clearly about exact reason of why RegisterAction cannot accept some actions.

Comment: "it is better" -- I have to disagree. It depends on the situation. It's often a nicer solution to `static_assert`, but it's often necessary to SFINAE. SFINAE also does reveal the reason why the overload was rejected, it's just harder to decipher.