# How to constrain a template? Six different usages of std::enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, compile-time

I'm trying to understand two different versions of a template function that uses `std::enable_if<>`.

**Version 1:**

```
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, std::string_view>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
void foo(const T& msg);
```

**Version 2:**

```
template<class T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, std::string_view>::value>::type>
void foo(const T& msg);
```

If I understood it correctly, if the condition is met they should be converted into:

```
// Version 1
template<class T, T* = nullptr>
void foo(const T& msg);

// Version 2
template<class T, typename = void>
void foo(const T& msg);
```

Both versions can be equally called by:

```
std::string s = "Test";
foo(s);
```

What is the difference between those two versions? When should one be used?

---

### Second question

Because of an error on my part, I discovered that version 2 also compiles, if one typename is missing:

```
//Correct Version 2 like above:
template<class T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, std::string_view>::value>::type>
void foo(const T& msg);

// My "faulty" version, also works. Is this correct too?
template<class T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, std::string_view>::value>::type>
void foo(const T& msg);
```

Is the second (faulty) version also correct? I thought `std::enable_if<>` does need a `typename` in front of it.

Comment: First question: The major difference is that the former cannot be circumvented by manually specifying some other value for the second template parameter. Suppose `nc` an object of some type `NoConvert` that isn't convertible to a `std::string_view`. We can't call `foo(nc)`, but we could call `foo<NoConvert, void>(nc);` or `foo<NoConvert, int>(nc);` or w/e because the `enable_if` type was just a default value for the second template parameter and you can always specify a non-default value. On the other hand in version 1, the type of the argument itself is the `enable_if` so you can't bypass it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427667/sfinae-working-in-return-type-but-not-as-template-parameter

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, that would have been my next question, why I cant have Version 2 with another, different if expression. So in general, Version 1 should be always preferred? Version 2 can be circumvented and can only exist with one if expression.

Comment: Version 1 is my SFINAE of choice.

Comment: BTW: Does anybody have a suggestion for a better title of this question? I don't think the current title is that great for searching...

Comment: Second question: [doesn't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/f1eYGETPc) for me. A compiler that accepts this without error is incorrect, I believe.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Compiler is VisualStudio 2019 MSVC compiler. Compiled with c++17 flag.

Comment: C++20 makes that `typename` optional; perhaps the compiler is “being nice” in C++17 mode?

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks. Do you have a link where this behavior regarding typename  is described?

Comment: Re typename, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_typename_disambiguator_for_dependent_names and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How should one constrain a template?

If you are not limited to compatibility with older C++ standards (pre C++20), and you don't need to refer to the template type, and the constraints only involve a single template parameter, prefer the least boilerplate option:

```
// #1
void foo(const std::convertible_to<std::string_view> auto& msg);
```

Otherwise, prefer the slightly more verbose form:

```
// #2
template <typename T>
    requires std::convertible_to<T, std::string_view>
void foo(const T& msg);
```

The form #2 gives a name to the template type and continues to function if the constraints involve multiple template parameters. It is still not directly applicable to older C++, but the location of the constraint is compatible with older C++ `enable_if` usage:

```
// #2, compatible version

// C++11
#define TEMPLATE(...)            template <__VA_ARGS__
#define REQUIRES(C)              , typename std::enable_if<(C), int>::type = 0>
#define CONVERTIBLE_TO(From, To) std::is_convertible<From, To>::value

// C++20
#define TEMPLATE(...)            template <__VA_ARGS__>
#define REQUIRES(C)              requires (C)
#define CONVERTIBLE_TO(From, To) std::convertible_to<From, To>

TEMPLATE(typename T)
    REQUIRES(CONVERTIBLE_TO(T, std::string_view))
void foo(const T& msg);
```

The following options are also available, but I would stick to #1 or #2:

```
// #3
template <std::convertible_to<std::string_view> T>
void foo(const T& msg);

// #4
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& msg) requires std::convertible_to<T, std::string_view>;
```

With respect to `enable_if`, there are three options:

```
// #5, non-type template parameter with default value ("version 1")
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string_view>, int> = 0>
void foo(const T& msg);

// #6, enable_if in the return type
template<typename T>
auto foo(const T& msg) -> typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string_view>>;

// #7, defaulted template parameter ("version 2")
template<class T, typename = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string_view>>>
void foo(const T& msg);
```

Option #7 ("version 2") is rarely advisable, because default template parameters do not participate in the function signature. So, once you have two overloads, it is ambiguous. And overload sets grow.

Option #6 is not available for constructors, which lack a return type. But, in #6, you can name the function parameters which can be handy.

Option #5 is the most general SFINAE option. Prefer it, if you must SFINAE.

Regarding question #2, the relaxation on typename came in C++20, and is described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_typename_disambiguator_for_dependent_names) and [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation! I really wonder it has not received more views yet :)